# how to select same select option in the next page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[image]I have a select tag in my home page, if I selected an option in that select tag  and then  I moved on to another page(second page) then the same option which I selected in the home page should be selected in the select tag of second page

```
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-3 " ng-hide="IsHidden" style="padding-top:10px;"  ng-init="ChildOrganization()">
            <select class="form-control custom-form-control" ng-model="Child" ng-options="Organization.OrganizationName for Organization in ChildOrganization track by Organization.organizationId" ng-change = "childorganizationId(Child)">
            <option value="" selected="selected">{{OrganizationName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far...

Comment: you can use sessions to pass data between pages. or you can use the query string

Comment: @silverstrike but for me is getting renaming selected radio button . eg: see the attached image

Comment: @sunilkumareu this tag selected="selected" should only be present for the selected option. is it?

Comment: @silverstrike yes only for the selected option

Comment: How do you navigate between the pages?

Answer (score 1):

For getting the option selected you don't need to use this -

`<option value="" selected="selected">{{OrganizationName}}</option>`

you can just assign `$scope.Child = 'Organization Name'` and value will get selected in dropdown.

Secondly for your dropdown to be same in all pages you can put it in your index.html(or some partial view) and then use $rootScope to access it in all the pages.